# Why jquery.ui.all.css for Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I wonder what `jquery.ui.all.css` does to `Tabs`

The moment I remove

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/dev/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
```

My tabs dont work..

My question is:

What do `jquery.ui.all.css stylesheet` actually do to tabs?

Can I create my own stylesheet for the tabs and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the styles related to the tabs are in the jquery.ui.all.css style sheet..

The tabs are actually normal html elements like div and span which are encased in wrappers.
If you remove the stylesheets the actual element's are displayed on the screen..

These wrappers are associated with class names which give styles to the tabs.

If you want to write up your own styles you need to override or style each wrapper in which these are encased in..

There is a easier way to style up the custom styles by using the

[Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/Themeroller)

Answer (score 0):

If you [open the file](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css), this is what you would see:

```
/*!
 * jQuery UI CSS Framework 1.8.23
 *
 * Copyright 2012, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming
 */
@import "jquery.ui.base.css";
@import "jquery.ui.theme.css";
```

Those two `@import` statements load those two separate files when this file is included. It's a shortcut, one that [replaced the following](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/d8841a752b594921ab88a14fd92d8a6c3e19e0f8/themes/base/ui.all.css) ([**DIFF**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/828bcdd2f0befbf450dcd1d7c387388acd7a191b/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css)) back in February, 2010:

```
@import "ui.core.css";
@import "ui.accordion.css";
@import "ui.datepicker.css";
@import "ui.dialog.css";
@import "ui.progressbar.css";
@import "ui.resizable.css";
@import "ui.slider.css";
@import "ui.tabs.css";
```

So if you remove that include, I would assume that more than just the jQuery UI tabs would stop working, unless that's the only UI-based effect you're using.